# Will an upgrade to Android 4.3 update Google Maps automatically (to the new unloved version)?

Tags: nexus-4, google-maps, 4.3-jelly-bean

My nexus 4 is notifying me about the availability of the new installation image for Android 4.3. I would like to install it, but I'm afraid this would automatically update Google Maps to the newest version. The comments about the removed features in Maps are so bad, that I want to stay with the old version for a while.

So, what happens to Google Maps when I upgrade to Android 4.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not update Google Maps. You will have to update that manually or through Google Play. However, after you download and install the OTA update, you may receive a Google Map update notification. Just make sure you don't set your Google Play apps to auto-update, so you can close / ignore those notifications.

Source: [Comments on CNet](http://reviews.cnet.com/operating-systems/google-android-4-3/4505-3671_7-35760688.html).

Comment: I followed the link, but found nothing about Google Maps there.

Comment: @tangens Read the comments. It's there. :)

Comment: I upgraded to 4.3 and everything else stayed unchanged.

Comment: Yesterday I upgraded to 4.4 and Google Maps was updated automatically :-( It's really awful now. I wish I had not upgraded to 4.4!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. I updated and now I have the new Maps. Knox security prevents you from installing any apks, and you can't kill Knox, so if you don't want the new Maps don't install the OTA.

Comment: Samsung likely decided (for whatever reason) to package the new Maps update in their OTA, so this is probably not relevant to the specific situation the OP was interested in (i.e. the Nexus 4). The Nexus 4 also doesn't have Knox.